# Why is the fractional Sobolev space defined like this?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I was reading Fractional Sobolev space topic.

$s\in (0,1)$, $p\in [1,\infty)$,

$$
W^{s,p}(\Omega)=\left\{u\in L^p(\Omega)|\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{n/p+s}}\in L^p(\Omega\times \Omega)\right\}
$$.

But I do know why there is extra term of $n/p$ come in power. Natural extension of integer Sobolev space should be
$$
W^{s,p}(\Omega)=\left\{u\in L^p(\Omega)|\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{s}}\in L^p(\Omega\times \Omega)\right\}
$$.

Please any one through some light on such definition of Sobolev space.

Edit: I though may be this because of integrability possible iff $(n/p+s)p>n$. But I am not sure.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If e.g. $u\in L^1$ with compact support for simplicity in $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$, then
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^{2n}} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^s} \ dxdy \le\int_{\operatorname{supp} u}|u(x)|\int_{\operatorname{supp} u}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}dydx + \int_{\operatorname{supp} u}|u(y)|\int_{\operatorname{supp} u}\frac{1}{|x-y|^s}dxdy \le C\|u\|_{L^1} $$
for any $s<n$, nevermind $s<1$, as
$$\int_{\text{bounded set}} \frac{dz}{|z|^s} < \infty. $$ Consequently, the condition  $ \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^s}\in L^1(\mathbb R^{2n})$ fails to ask for any new regularity properties on $L^1$ functions.

You may also look to [the Hitchhiker's guide to fractional sobolev spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345) for the computation that $\left\| \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{n/2+s}}\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^{2n},dxdy)} = C_{n,s} \| |\xi|^s \hat f(\xi)\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n,d\xi)}  $, which explains (in the case $p=2$) the appearance of the $n/2$.